# how to set the groups content in single page for row groups in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, sql-server-data-tools, page-break

I am trying to design a report in SSRS in which there are multiple row groups. When I am trying to preview the report the page is getting break for certain groups even if there is blank space in the page. Here in the image below some of the content of Page 2 in report can be adjusted in page 1  [image: Figure 1]. The design of the report is  [image: this]. I have tried to set the Keep Together property in the property of row group to false. Even if I set the Kepp Together to false I am getting the same result.

Have anyone encounter such problem? If yes, I shall be highly grateful for your valuable suggestion for solving the problem please.

Comment: From your design, I think the entire block on page 2 starting at `MH    4711` down to `Total Voted 410000` would have to fit into the remaining space on page 1, which there is clearly not enough room for.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I mean `MH  4711` till `60 Original works` can be adjusted in blank space in page 1