# Un-necessary page break in SSRS Reporting Service 15.0.7961

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2019

I was trying to generate PDF from which book `(1000-2000 pages)` is printed. With referece to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73867122/how-to-set-the-groups-content-in-single-page-for-row-groups-in-ssrs), I am fighting with the SSRS Report page break issue wherein I have following cases:

**Case 1:** Page is getting break with desired content in the page but no header in the next page.

**Case 2:** Page is getting break in the middle of the group with the space in the bottom wherein some content can be added and Table header is repeating on the next page.

I am getting mad while solving the issue as I cannot identify where the problem is. I have tried to set the group property `keepTogether` to `true` for the groups. I have tried to set `Interactive Height` to 0 as well. I have also tried to bring the sub report in the main report by adding another dataset but it allows me to add only the first of the second dataset. I wonder this kind of problem is also faced by many developers around the globe, However, I have tried as much as I can since I am stucked in this problem for more than a week. Solutions and suggestion to the problem surely be appreciated please.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the size of the body over report especially width?

example:
if you have a report with in an A4 size paper which has a width of 8.27in.

If the body of your report is having a width more than 8.27, even a very very small, this will result to new page every after instance.

this is the same with other components.

example:
if you have subreport that exceed the max of the width of your report, this will result again to new page every after instance.

moreover, there are many things to consider but I think sizing is the one that causes the issue